# Microsoft SQL Server JDBC connection debugging

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL Server in a very vanilla Java 17 Spring Boot application.

### Context

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.1.jre17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc_auth</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.1.x86</version>
    <type>dll</type>
</dependency>
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://domain.name;databaseName=DBNAME;
spring.datasource.username=ORGANIZATION\\username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

My simple query, running as a scheduled job:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 100000)
public void doAFlip() {
    Map<String, Object> m = template.queryForMap("SELECT 1");
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

### Error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'ORGANIZATION\username'. ClientConnectionId:53139a88-ea29-4a7e-a576-10a1a91131be
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:83) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:465) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:475) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:508) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForMap(JdbcTemplate.java:502) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at com.example.demo.Foo.doAFlip(Foo.java:17) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'ORGANIZATION\username'. ClientConnectionId:53139a88-ea29-4a7e-a576-10a1a91131be
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:299) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:132) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6154) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4777) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4715) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7730) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3786) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3233) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2833) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2671) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1640) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:936) ~[mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre17.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

### Details

I am confident that this username and password are correct, because I can connect and query the database in Go using identical credentials. If it helps, my connection string in Go is as follows:

```
server=domain.name;user id=ORGANIZATION\\username;password=password;port=1433;database=DBNAME;
```

I am at a loss as to why I can connect in Go, but not Java. I am interested in potential solutions, and also ways that I can debug this.

Comment: starting with version 10.2, the JDBC driver encryption is [enabled by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#changes-in-102).  Try adding `;encrypt=false` to the end of the datasource url.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Windows/Active Directory credentials to connect to a "Windows Logon" account in SQL Server. The various *DBC drivers unfortunately have different parameter/invocation requirements for each of the common authentication methods. Have you read the [Using NTLM Authentication to connect to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server) documentation yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes! You solved my problems! This was one of these problems where I know so little about the underlying technology that I don't even know what to ask. You were 100% correct- I needed to use NTLM.

The docs you linked me might be old, because I can't find SQLServerDataSource in the mssql-jdbc 10.x jar. That said, I did need to specify authScheme to get things to work. Here's my working properties file:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://uri:1433;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM;domain=ORG;
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=***